# bilinear form, anti symmetric part

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$\mathcal{H}$ : real Hilbert space with inner product $(\,,\,)$ and norm $||\,||:=(\,,\,)^{1/2}$

Let $D$ be a linear subspace of $\,\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ : $D\times D\to \mathbb{R}$ a bilinear map.　We define its symmetric part and anti symmetric part $(\tilde{\mathcal{E}},D), (\check{\mathcal{E}},D)$ respectively by

$\tilde{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{E}(u,v)+\mathcal{E}(v,u))$; $\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)=\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{E}(u,v)-\mathcal{E}(v,u))$, $u,v \in D$

For $\alpha\geq0$ we set
$\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,v):=\mathcal{E}(u,v)+\alpha(u,v)\quad(\,u,v \in D )$

Assume $\mathcal{E}(u,u)\geq 0$ for all $ u \in D  $

I want to show that for all $\alpha \geq0$  the following assertion are equivalent:

$(a)$ $\exists K_{\alpha}>0$ s.t. $\mathcal{E}(u,v)\leq K_{\alpha}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}$ for all $u,v \in D$

$(b)$ $\exists K_{\alpha}'>0$ s.t. $\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)\leq K_{\alpha}'\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}$ for all $u,v \in D$

---

My solution is as follows:

$(a) \Rightarrow(b)$:

$|\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)|=|\frac{1}{2}(\mathcal{E}(u,v)-\mathcal{E}(v,u))|
\leq\frac{1}{2}(|\mathcal{E}(u,v)|+|\mathcal{E}(v,u)|)$
$\leq\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2K_{\alpha}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2} $

i.e. $|\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)|\leq K_{\alpha}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2} $

$(b) \Rightarrow (a)$:

First of all, I will show the case of $\alpha>0$.

$\mathcal{E}(u,v)=\tilde{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)+\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)=\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)+\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)-\alpha(u,v)$

therefore $|\mathcal{E}(u,v)|\leq |\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)|+|\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)|+|\alpha(u,v)|$

Remark1: $\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)$ is inner product. Hence $|\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)|\leq \tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,u)^{1/2}\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(v,v)^{1/2}$

Remark2: $\alpha|(u,v)|\leq \alpha\|u\|\|v\|\leq\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}$

accordingly,

$|\mathcal{E}(u,v)|\leq \tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,u)^{1/2}\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(v,v)^{1/2}+|\check{\mathcal{E}}(u,v)|+\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}$

$\leq \tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,u)^{1/2}\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(v,v)^{1/2}+K_{\alpha}'\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}+\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2} $

$=\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}+K_{\alpha}'\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}+\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2} $

$=(K_{\alpha}'+2)\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(u,u)^{1/2}\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}(v,v)^{1/2} $

In the case of $\alpha=0$, $\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)$ is not always inner product. How do I show the case of $\alpha=0$? Please tell me.

Comment: $|\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,v)|\leq \tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(u,u)^{1/2}\tilde{\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}}(v,v)^{1/2}$ is true for all $\alpha\geq 0$.

Comment: $\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_{0}(u,v)$ is certainly not inner product product($\tilde{\mathcal{E}}_{\alpha}(u,u)$=0 \nRightarrow u=0) but this inequality holds. I didn't notice at all. Thanks to your support, I could solve this problem.